# Find a character in a list of words

Tags: python

I am trying to find a specific character in a list of words and then print all the words that match. for example, I have a list of 6 words. I would like to find a way to select all the words with a ('.') (fullstop) in them and transfer them to another list.

Example:

```
List ['alpha', 'bravo', 'charlie.', 'delta', 'echo']
```

I would like it to find Charlie and its position in the list

I mostly just need the if statement for it
Thanks in advance!

This is what I have so far

```
sent = str(input('enter sentance '))
words = sent.split()
print (words)
```

Comment: `List [alpha, bravo, charlie., delta, echo]` isn't valid Python code. I guess maybe `alpha`, `bravo`, `charlie.`, `delta` and `echo` should be in quotes? And `List` should probably be `list`?

Comment: its just a quick example not meant to be actual code more pseudocode

Comment: Pseudocode is only helpful when it is clear. (Clarity is its purpose.) In this case it's probably better to use actual Python code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want it without list comprehension:

```
sent = input('Enter sentence > ')
words = sent.split()
for word in words:
    if "." in word:
        print(word)
```

Also, you if you're in Python 2.7, use `raw_input`, `input` for Python 3.

Comment: That's it eric, nice one, plus one :)

Answer (score 3):

Assume you have a list `l = ['alpha', 'bravo', 'charlie.', 'delta', 'echo']`
Then you can create a list with all words containing '.' in it by doing filter like below:

```
l = ['alpha', 'bravo', 'charlie.', 'delta', 'echo']
list_with_dot = [x for x in l if x.find('.') != -1]
```

Comment: yeeeeah... like it so much, very nice gipsy. it's a plus one for me

Answer (score 1):

you can try this (for python 2.7)

```
sent = raw_input('enter sentance ')


lista = ['alpha', 'bravo', 'charlie.', 'delta', 'echo']

res = [i for i in lista if (sent in i)][0]

print(str(res) + "is at index " + str(lista.index(res)))
```

Answer (score 1):

The usual way to know if a character is in a string in python is "in"

```
'.' in "charlie."
```

that will return True.

To know the position of an element in a list you can iterate using enumerate(list) and will return a pair of (index,value).

To get a list of the index and the strings who have '.' character you can do something like this:

```
[(pos, word) for pos, word in enumerate(list) if '.' in word]
```